# Fasle positive alerts in my app (AV)

Tags: vb.net, windows, registry, antivirus, false-positive

I have made a programm that modifies the Windows-Registry so you can add shortcuts to the contextmenu on the Desktop.

On my computer everything is fine, but when i switch to another PC with an AV, it gets a positive alert (I acsess HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT)

I need a way, when there is one, to fix it, because users that rely on their AV will get scared.

[GitHub](https://github.com/amir00t/LvL-up)

Comment: Naturally a virus scanner is going to freak out when a program starts modifying global registry settings. That's exactly the type of behavior malware would have. The only thing that distinguishes your application from malware is that, hopefully, the user *wants* to do it. No, there's no workaround, other than proper documentation.

Comment: `when i switch to another PC with an AV` - You don't use any AntiVirus software?? O.o

Comment: I do xDD but another one (I use ESET Smart Security [the best one ive ever had, but the one with the most "false" alerts] and the computer which needed the tweaks had Avira) lmao i made a huuuuge mistake

Comment: @CodyGray It wasn't even starting and it already stopped

Comment: Even if it *were* completely fixed/answered, "[SOLVED]" doesn't belong in titles here. I don't use antivirus or antimalware software of any kind, @vincent. The false positives are too annoying to me, as is the drag it causes on performance. I just have enough sense not to download shady apps or click things I don't trust. Anyway, if you want to talk about specific brands and false positives, I've found that Avast is the worst. Avira is usually pretty decent. But in this case, I'm surprised that ESET *isn't* warning about global registry modification attempts. You must have it configured not to

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution now.
I got it from the comments under my post

> Naturally a virus scanner is going to freak out when a program starts modifying global registry settings. That's exactly the type of behavior malware would have. The only thing that distinguishes your application from malware is that, hopefully, the user wants to do it. No, there's no workaround, other than proper documentation.